# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v1' has no attribute 'contrib'

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter, tensorflow2.0

```
x = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None, 28, 28])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int32, shape = [None])
images_flat = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(x)
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(images_flat, 62, tf.nn.relu)
loss = 
tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits( 
   labels = y, logits = logits))
   train_op = 
   tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)
   correct_pred = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
   accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, 
   tf.float32))

   print("images_flat: ", images_flat)
   print("logits: ", logits)
   print("loss: ", loss)
   print("predicted_labels: ", correct_pred)


AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-183722ce66a3> in <module>
      1 x = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None, 28, 28])
      2 y = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int32, shape = [None])
----> 3 images_flat = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(x)
      4 logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(images_flat, 62, tf.nn.relu)
      5 loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y, logits = logits))

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v1' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

2.This is my code in Jupyter Notebook.
I just started with python and get the error I mentioned in the headline. I would be very thankful if someone could help me wizh a code example to solve the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`tf.contrib` was removed from TensorFlow once with TensorFlow 2.0 alpha version.

Most likely, you are already using TensorFlow 2.0.

You can find more details here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha0

For using specific versions of tensorflow, use

```
pip install tensorflow==1.14
```

or

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14
```

Comment: is there any way to use the former version of tensor flow ? 
thank you for your help so far!

Comment: I updated the answer in order to answer to your additional question.

Comment: @TimbusCalin Unable to install tensorflow 1.14 either by pip or by conda. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

contrib is a headache of Google Team. We have to deal with the issue of contrib case by case. I just take two examples as follows.

**1.With regard to CNN, it has the following method**

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()

# -initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=1)
initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1)
```

**2.With regard to RNN/LSTM, it has the following different method.**

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()

# -outputs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cells, _X, dtype=tf.float32)
outputs, states = tf.compat.v1.nn.static_rnn(lstm_cells, _X, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Comment: Yes, instead of contrib and downgrade to tf1, searching for similar named thing in tf2's compat v1 and changing function is better.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, the contrib got deleted in TF2. So there is a quick solution to replace it with an estimator suggested here in this link

https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md

**in the case of using tf1**

tf.contib.layers.batch_norm throws error "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v1' has no attribute 'contrib'".

**Solution**:
tf.estimator.layers.batch_norm

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add the following line in your python file which you are going to execute it.

---

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

---

Comment: I tried this solution but it does not work because the TensorFlow contrib module is not included in TensorFlow 2.0. Only by downgrading to TensorFlow 1.0 it works.