# Attribute Error: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to load the tensorflow zoo model but I encountered this error and I am not able to fix this I am new to ai/ml. This is the code for loading the zoo model:

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'    # Suppress TensorFlow logging
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import config_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
from object_detection.builders import model_builder

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')           # Suppress TensorFlow logging (2)

# Enable GPU dynamic memory allocation
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

# Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(PATH_TO_CFG)
model_config = configs['model']
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=model_config,                                     
is_training=False)

# Restore checkpoint
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(os.path.join(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'ckpt-0')).expect_partial()

@tf.function
def detect_fn(image):
    """Detect objects in image."""

    image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
    detections = detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)

    return detections, prediction_dict, tf.reshape(shapes, [-1])
```

Comment: `tf.contrib` is not available in `Tensorflow version >= 2.0` also I do not see you using it at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow\_core.compat.v1' has no attribute 'contrib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644859/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-core-compat-v1-has-no-attribute-contrib)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @yudhiesh, tf.contrib is deprecated in Tensorflow >=2.0.
tf.contrib libraries are moved to [Tensorflow addons](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons).

Take a look at [Tensorflow release note](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md#release-200).